# Usage of \pgfkeysvalueof leads to 'Dimension too large'

Tags: pgfplots, errors, capacity

As the title already says, I got the problem that the Usage of `\pgfkeysvalueof` leads to an 'Dimension too large' error. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, samples=200}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    xtick={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}},
    ytick={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}},
    ]
\addplot[domain=-2:2, smooth, blue, thick]{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The curious thing is that this error only occurs on my Macbook while it isn't a problem for the iMac. On both machines is Mactex2016 installed, only the versions of pgfplots aren't the same.

Output of `tlmgr info pgfplots`in Terminal.app on the Macbook:

```
package:     pgfplots
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Create normal/logarithmic plots in two and three dimensions
longdesc:    ....
installed:   Yes
revision:    41838
sizes:       src: 993k, doc: 16189k, run: 3521k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.14
cat-date:    2016-08-11 04:56:10 +0200
cat-license: gpl3
cat-topics:  graphics-plot pgf-tikz
cat-related: pst-plot pgfplotstable
collection:  collection-pictures
```

And on the iMac:

```
package:     pgfplots
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Create normal/logarithmic plots in two and three dimensions
longdesc:    ...
installed:   Yes
revision:    40966
sizes:       src: 901k, doc: 15645k, run: 3429k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.13
cat-date:    2016-01-07 22:13:11 +0100
cat-license: gpl3
cat-topics:  graphics-plot pgf-tikz
cat-related: pst-plot pgfplotstable
collection:  collection-pictures
```

If I set the ticks manually by `xtick={-2,...,2}, ytick={-2,...,2}`, it also runs without any error on my Macbook. Is this a known bug or is there any way to handle it?

Edit: The version of pgfplots on the Macbook seems to be the newest one, at least `tlmgr update --all` doesn't list any available updates. If I copy the older pgfplots 1.13 from the iMac to the Macbook, the above MWE runs without an error.

Comment: I can confirm the 1.14 compilation error. My installation isn't bang up to date, but it is very recent. I am not prepared to update right now lest I break something, but can you try updating the MacBook? Perhaps 1.14 introduced a bug which is now fixed (or something else introduced one now fixed).

Comment: @cfr According to `tlmgr update --all` all packages seem to be up to date on the Macbook already. Since you can confirm the error, I think it would be a temporary solution for me to downgrade to 1.13 on the Macbook.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought that the macbook had an earlier version...will delete my comment

Comment: That's unfortunate. I guess the problem now is to figure out which change causes the issue. Can you copy the 1.13 pgfplots to the MacBook for testing purposes, to see if it is pgfplots itself or something else?

Comment: I can confirm that the above MWE worked in v1.13 and thus this bug was introduced with v1.14 which I added to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/150/).

Comment: @cfr I just copied the version 1.13 from the iMac to the Macbook. Now the MWE runs without any error.

Comment: I was going to suggest reporting it, but I see @StefanPinnow already did ;).

Comment: For the record: In PGFPlots v1.16 the bug is already fixed, but not in the current stable of PGF (v3.0.1a). When (someday) PGF will be released in a new stable as well, the issue will be totally fixed.